# write.table is not outputting a header for row names

Tags: r, matrix

I try to write out a matrix to csv while retaining rownames (c.f. [Export matrix in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844166/export-matrix-in-r)).

However when I do it using write.table() all the columns get shifted to the left (so the first data column header appears above the rownames column).

```
"PC1","PC2","PC3","PC4"
"Murder",0.0417043206282872,-0.04482165626967,0.0798906594208106,-0.994921731246978
"Assault",0.995221281426497,-0.0587600278572231,-0.0675697350838042,0.03893829763516
"UrbanPop",0.0463357461197111,0.976857479909889,-0.200546287353865,-0.0581691430589317
"Rape",0.0751555005855469,0.200718066450337,0.974080592182492,0.0723250196376096
```

I tried the following (to manually add an extra column):

```
merged.pca <- prcomp(USArrests)

write.table(merged.pca$rotation, file = "rotation.csv", sep = ",", col.names = c("rowname",colnames(merged.pca$rotation)))
```

Unfortunately this fails with:

```
Error in write.table(merged.pca$rotation, file = "rotation.csv", sep = ",",  : 
  invalid 'col.names' specification
```

TBH I have no clue what this error means. Is it something about the argument being a list and not a vector?

Comment: Pls provide us with some sample data. I guess you want to use `paste()` for you new col.names rather than `c()`,

Comment: Why would I want paste()? I'm just trying to prepend a column in front of all the regular ones (PC1, PC2, ..).
The output is what you get from prcomp, you can just put any valid matrix there, eg USArrests

Comment: OK, I've added the USArrests into the code, and also sample output

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per the help for `write.table`, you want to specify `col.names=NA`:

```
write.table(merged.pca$rotation, file="rotation.csv", col.names=NA, sep=",")
```

Yes, I think it's a bit silly too. Note that `write.csv` will do this for you automatically.

Comment: I must be going blind - somehow I missed this in the dosc. I accept this one since it's an exact anwser to my question.

Comment: @Hong Ooi Is it possible to add a name to the rownames column instead of the blank space?  I.e., call it "ID" instead of blank...

Answer (score 4):

If all else fails, you could make the rownames as column, e. g.

```
res <- transform(merged.pca$rotation, rowname=rownames(merged.pca$rotation))
write.table(res, "rotation.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: +1 for workable solution. Still it seems there should be something more straightforward. Actually I expected I was just missing something/being stupid

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether I completely understand but my shot is:

You save your matrix simply with

```
write.csv( merged.pca$rotation, file = "rotation.csv", row.names = TRUE )
```

You load it (as a data.frame!) with

```
x <- read.csv( "rotation.csv" )
```

and bring it back to the previous format with

```
row.names( x ) <- x[,1]
x <- as.matrix( x[-1] )
```

Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

This solution saves the column structure (ie., for Excel) and names:

### To write a file in MacRoman for simple use in Mac Excel 2004/8

`write.csv(x, file = "foo.csv", fileEncoding = "macroman")`

### or for Windows Excel 2007/10

`write.csv(x, file = "foo.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-16LE")`